# why the output of curve fitting is not true?

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a curve into my data. my function is polynomial order 3 as bellow:

```
def objective3(x, a, b, c,d):
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c * x**3 +d
y=center_1080[itr,:]
x=[1000 ,2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000]
popt, pcov,info,msg, ier= curve_fit(objective3, x, y,full_output=True)
a, b, c ,d= popt
```

`y` has the same shape as `x`. after that I used the following code to find the new values based on this curve for y:

```
x_line4 = arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line4 = objective3(x_line4, a, b, c,d)
```

suppose `x_line4` value is as follows (shape (5,):

```
11995
11996
11997
11998
11999
```

when I use `objective3(x_line4,a,b,c,d)` the output is:

```
66.4718
66.4732
66.4746
66.4759
66.4773
```

but when I use each element of x_line4 separately as input the output is different. for example `objective3(11999,a,b,c,d)=81.11075844620781`but `objective3(x_line4[4],a,b,c,d)=66.4773`!!!! what is the problem? `a=0.003184157353698613,b=-2.2820353448818053e-07,c=8.475420387015893e-12,d=61.11802131658904`

Comment: Most unclear. What do you mean by 'true'?? [ask] and [mre]

Comment: It's unclear to me too. You need to post the sample data - ```y``` in your case. Did you plot the ```y``` and ```y_line4```? Also use the term 'error' instead of true or false.

Comment: I have added an example. I am baffled about different outputs. why does python do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is an int-overflow:
The type of `x_line4[4]` is `int32` which is limited to `2,147,483,648`. If you plug in `11999` instead, you still have an int that is in principle limited to the same range, but Python seems to perform automated adjustment of the `int` from a `int32` to an `int64` or something alike under the hood (not sure here).

For the individual numbers, the easiest thing to do is to add `x = float(x)` in the first row of your function `objective3`. If you expect your function to handle both single numbers as well as numpy arrays, you will have to check whether it is an numpy array using something like this:

```
import numpy as np

def objective3(x, a, b, c,d):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        x.astype(float)
    else:
        x = float(x)
    return a * x + b * x**2 + c * x**3 +d
```

Alternatively, you could also ensure that all numpy arrays are float arrays instead.

Edit: Just for clarification: The part where the error occurs is the `x**3` since that value is above the maximum value an `int32` can hold.